# Rotating the texture

Tags: materials, uv, texture-coordinates

I have a problem where the texture is on the wrong side.I want it in the middle of the sphere (left arrow). Rotating it did not fix it either. I was wondering if anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of reasons this may happen.  When you mix noise into your coordinate space it can offset the object origin by some amount.  You can attempt to counteract this by adjusting the *Location* on the *Mapping* node.

In the case that rotation is not working correctly, it may help to add a second *Mapping* node behind it and do the rotation separately.  I think there is a set order of operations that you must override.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207071/110840

Comment: Yeah, idk why i did not think of that tbh. Thanks for the help